# Call a function in another class that read a dynamic variable via IBaction

Tags: ios, swift, function, variables

I'm trying to call a function stored on another class:

**ViewController**

```
@IBAction func refreshComments() {
    CommentsTableViewController().refresh()
}
```

**CommentsTableViewController**

```
 var variable2 = "0"

 func refresh(){
     print(variable2)
  }
```

This works great, but in my case the value of my variable its not a static value, I've receive dynamically this value, and I know the problem is in this line :

```
//CommentsTableViewController().refresh()
```

Because `CommentsTableViewController()` - this is class constructor and each time I call `CommentsTableViewController()` it return a new instance/object of `CommentsTableViewController` class, with default values of course.

So I'm really stuck at this point and I don't know how to solve this. I've already tried to transform the func `refresh()` a class `funcrefresh()` and call this way :

```
@IBAction func refreshComments() {
CommentsTableViewController.refresh()
}
```

But in this way I got a error that I'm not able to read the variable2

> print(variable2) - Instance member 'variable2'cannot be used on type 'CommentsTableViewController'

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Follows my hierarchy:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling Controller to Controller in a container is a bit difficult. Try to fill the container programaticly. Otherwise you will not have the controll over the controller.

You could also work with Notifications, but notifications shouldnt be used for one to one communication.

**Create Programaticly**

- You have an Container and link an IBOutlet to your MainController.
- you also create a property for the CommentsViewController
- in the storyboard give your controller a storyboardIdentifier
- in viewDidLoad of your main controller you instanciate the commentsController property with the controller from the storyboard.
- add the controller as childViewController to the mainController and add the view from your CommentsViewController to the containerView
- could be that you need to set the view.frame from the commentsViewController to the same as the containerView

now you have a controller property and you can run any public function.

*Sorry for no code example. I got currently not much time :)*

**Notifcations**

Your Main View Controller will send a Notification to a specific name and the CommentsViewController will observer this Notification and make an action when receiving it.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(name:"YourNameYouLike")
```

In your commentsViewController you observe this notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(name:"theSameNameThatYourPostNotificationDidUse", object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { [weak self] in 
    guard s = self else { return } 
    s.reload()
}
```

Comment: you are the master! Worked perfectly! Thanks for the completely explanation. Have a nice day/night.

Comment: Great that i could be a help. My writtings are a little bit shitty. I should take care of the correct words ... ehe

Answer (score 0):

you should store the the controller in a property of the caller. Than you can call the refresh function from the property and the variable can change.

Comment: Seems pretty logical to me, but I don't know how to implement, can you you give me a practical example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your view controller hierarchy is laid down but you should not initialise `CommentsTableViewController` every time you need to call `refresh` function.

Believing your `variable2` being modified from within `CommentsTableViewController` and holds the dynamic value as mentioned, you should call `refresh` function on the already existing object of `CommentsTableViewController` that holds the latest and greatest property values.

Hope this makes sense to you!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I believe this way It's not gonna work to me, because `CommentesTableViewController` is a Container inside my `ViewController` and in my `ViewController` I have a NavigationButtonItem that needs to call the function that stored on the another class.

Comment: I understand and I truly believe that you can get hold on to your container object inside `ViewController` and use that. Thats the prime way out as I can see it. Otherwise, try to pass `variable2` to `refresh` function ensuring `ViewController` has visibility to `variable2`'s dynamic value.